# SSH is not working for some VMs in MS Azure

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I created 4 virtual machine under one cloud service in Microsoft Azure. I tried to ssh to the VMs I created. I am able to do shh to first tow VMs, but not to the last two. What would be the problem. Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if all the vms have a public IP address.
If not, you need to use the first one to connect to the others, or assign them a public ip.